# Conversion Tracking on 3rd party Website using Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics

I have the following scenario:

Website A contains product description and links to the booking website B where the user places his order.

I need to track conversions placed on the website B and have them displayed in the Google Analytics account of the website A (which I controll). Website A is owned by me, website B is a 3rd party website but I can have their webmaster insert tags in their GTM.

Both websites use GTM for analytics tracking code.

So far I have cross domain tracking setup.

Website A has following setup:
Cookie-Domain: auto
allowLinker: true
autoLinkDomains contains domain of the website B

Website B has following setup:
Cookie-Domain: auto
allowLinker: true
autoLinkDomains contains domain of the website A

In GA account of the website A I have added the domain of the website B to the referral exclusion list.

So far good, the links on the website A are being decorated with the linker parameters so the website be receives the client ID.

Now comes the problem part: I didn't find any explanation of how I should now report the conversions which are done on the website B to the google Analytics account of the Website A. I only want to report the conversions for which the Website A accounts because the Website B has many other traffic sources!

How can this be achieved? As said I can have webmaster of the website B to configure their GTM tags accordingly when I know what to configure there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it probably belongs here https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same GA tracker ID must be used for A and B sites. That is you should add tracker from your site A to site B. Or create the new one.

**Settings**

`autoLinkDomains` must contain both domains comma separated. `cookieDomain` variable must be set to `auto`. Both domains needs to be added to referral exclusion list. For sure test your cross-domain linking.

**Report in GA**

Try to create segment: include sessions where `Hostname` equals to domain of site A. And then apply this segment on report contains any dimension and conversions (on site B).